# Yii Session not getting over

Tags: php, session, yii

I am trying to change the default session time out value. In my controller i have done this:

```
  public function beforeAction($action) {
    $session = new CHttpSession;
    $timeout = $session->getTimeout();
    if ($timeout != 10) {
      $session->setTimeout(10);
    }
    return true;
  }
```

But my session never gets timed out an i can access the page even after being inactive for 10 sec.

I also tried to do it through config by session component like this:

```
   'session' => array(
            'sessionName' => SITE_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
            'class' => 'CHttpSession',
            'timeout' => 10
        ),
```

but same result. Session dosent time out! Am I missing out on something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to turn off autostart session in configs:

> ```
> 'session' => array(
>         'sessionName' => SITE_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
>         'class' => 'CHttpSession',
>         'autoStart' => false
>     ),
> ```

In this case you need manually starting session: `Yii::app()->session->open()`, but BEFORE IT for changing life time try do:

> ```
> Yii::app()->session->open($session_lifetime);
> $cook_p = Yii::app()->session->getCookieParams();
> $cook_p['lifetime'] = $session_lifetime;
> Yii::app()->session->setCookieParams($cook_p);
> ```

OR you may inherit CHttpSession with new parameter `lifetime` and do it in method `init()`:

> ```
> class MyHttpSession extends CHttpSession{
>    public $lifetime = false;
>    public function init()
>    {
>       if($this->lifetime !== false){
>           $cook_p = $this->getCookieParams();
>           $cook_p['lifetime'] = $this->lifetime;
>           $this->setCookieParams($cook_p);
>           $this->setTimeout($this->lifetime);
>       }
>       parent::init();
>    }
> ```
>
> }

and in configs:

> ```
> 'session' => array(
>         'sessionName' => SITE_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
>         'class' => 'MyHttpSession',
>         'lifetime' => 60 // 1 minute
>     ),
> ```

Comment: But when i use 'autoStart' => false, the session does not start even in 1st request and i get Undefined variable: _SESSION

Comment: Yes, you're right. Lifetime of session can be changed before starting session. That's why my proposal is start session manually or you can inherit HttpSession (see how, i'm updated my post)

Comment: and where would this file be placed?

Comment: You can place it in `/protected/components` or another, but it directory must be imported (in `import` param)

Comment: This is giving me Undefined property: CWebApplication::$session

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40172/discussion-between-sankalp-mishra-and-creator)

Answer (score 1):

The `class` in the `session` array should apparently be `CDbHttpSession` for this to work.
See [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/13733-standard-yii-logout-timeout/page__view__findpost__p__67848) for a similar issue..

Comment: If i use CDbHttpSession i get error "CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver"

Comment: Yes, CDbHttpSession needs a database connection as the name implies. The relevant details are listed [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbHttpSession).

Answer (score 0):

for session timeout based on user being in-active for 30 minutes, in configs:

```
'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=> true,
            'autoRenewCookie'=> true,
            'authTimeout' => 1800
        ),
        'session' => array(
                    'class' => 'FrontCHttpSession',
                    'savePath' => dirname(__FILE__),
                    'cookieMode' => 'allow',
                    'cookieParams' => array(
                            'path' => '/',
                            'domain' => 'mydomain.com',
                            'httpOnly' => true,
                            'lifetime' => 1800
                    ),
                    'timeout' => 1800
        ),
```

Extended session class, similar idea can be used for CDbHttpSession

```
<?php

class FrontCHttpSession extends CHttpSession
{

      /*default is 0 which means the cookie lifetime will last as long as the browser is open*/
      private $_clientLifetime;
      /*time in seconds how long the session should remain open after user in-activity*/
      private $_sessionTimeout;
      /*cookie params defined in config*/
      private $_cookieParams;

      /**
      * Starts the session if it has not started yet.
      */

      public function open()
      {

            $this->_cookieParams = $this->getCookieParams();
            $this->_clientLifetime = $this->_cookieParams['lifetime'];
            $this->_sessionTimeout = $this->timeout;

            if($this->getUseCustomStorage())
                  @session_set_save_handler(array($this,'openSession'),
                        array($this,'closeSession'),
                        array($this,'readSession'),
                        array($this,'writeSession'),
                        array($this,'destroySession'),
                        array($this,'gcSession'));

            //session is already started, check if session has been not been active longer than timeout     
            if (session_id() != '')
            {
                  if ($this->get('last_active') < time() - $this->_sessionTimeout)
                  {
                      $this->destroy();
                  }
                  else if ($this->_clientLifetime > 0)
                  {
                      $this->updateSessionCookieExpire();
                  }
            }

            @session_set_cookie_params($this->_clientLifetime, array($this->_cookieParams['path'], 
                  $this->_cookieParams['domain'], $this->_cookieParams['secure'], $this->_cookieParams['httpOnly']));

            @session_start();
            $this->add('last_active', time());

            if(YII_DEBUG && session_id()=='')
            {

                  $message=Yii::t('yii','Failed to start session.');

                  if(function_exists('error_get_last'))

                  {

                        $error=error_get_last();

                        if(isset($error['message']))

                              $message=$error['message'];

                  }

                  Yii::log($message, CLogger::LEVEL_WARNING, 'system.web.CHttpSession');

            }

      }

      public function updateSessionCookieExpire() 
      {
            if (isset(Yii::app()->request->cookies[$this->getSessionName()])) 
            {
                  $c = Yii::app()->request->cookies[$this->getSessionName()]; 
                  $c->expire = time() + $this->_clientLifetime;
                  $c->path = $this->_cookieParams['path'];
                  $c->domain = $this->_cookieParams['domain'];
                  $c->httpOnly = $this->_cookieParams['httponly'];
                  $c->secure = $this->_cookieParams['secure'];
                  Yii::app()->request->cookies[$this->getSessionName()] = $c;
            }
      }

}
```